# Reflection in terms of simple reflections

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose $\beta=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\alpha_i$, where $\alpha_i$ are simple roots. Is there any easier way to write the reflection corresponding to $\beta$ say $s_{\beta}$ in terms of $s_{\alpha_i}$'s. I mean is there any formula to express $s_{\beta}$ as a product of $s_{\alpha_i}$'s.

Comment: I don't want to say no, but I think it's unlikely that some simple formula exists. There may be an algorithmic procedure, but the solution is not unique, so this would have to involve either arbitrary choices, or the input of a bit more information than just $\beta$. The expressions can get quite complicated - for example, you can see a choice of expression for the reflection in the longest root in each finite simple root system on page 15 of the following paper by Benkart-Kang-Oh-Park: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.1048v3.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your best hope is $$s_{\beta} = w s_{\alpha} w^{-1},$$ where $\beta = w(\alpha)$ for some simple root $\alpha$. It is always possible to write $\beta = w(\alpha)$ when $\beta$ is a root.

There are many possibilities for $w$ and $\alpha$. Define the depth of a positive root $\beta$ to be the smallest $k$ such that $w(\beta)$ is negative and $\ell(w) = k$. (See chapter 4 of ``Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups'' for further details.)

It's clear that simple roots have depth 1. It's not hard to show that the depth of $s_{\alpha_i}(\beta)$ is smaller than the depth of $\beta$ if $\langle \beta, \alpha_i \rangle > 0$. This provides a brute force procedure for finding $w$ (and $\alpha$) and expressing it as a product of simple reflections.

This is just an elaboration of Matt Pressland's comment. A good general formula appears to be too much to ask for. However, in type A (with the simple roots ordered in the usual way), there is a nice answer: $$\beta = \alpha_i + \cdots + \alpha_j \implies s_\beta = s_{\alpha_i} s_{\alpha_{i+1}} \cdots s_{\alpha_{j-1}}s_{\alpha_j}s_{\alpha_{j-1}}\cdots s_{\alpha_i}$$